# Removing Cocos2D from a ViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

I have a normal storyboard in an iOS app. It contains ViewController "A" with a button. When that button is tapped, it loads a Cocos2D view - to do this I simply copied the code from the default AppDelegate that you get when you create a new Cocos2D project:

```
window_ = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   
                               depthFormat:0    
                        preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                sharegroup:nil
                             multiSampling:NO
                           numberOfSamples:0];

[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

[director_ setDisplayStats:YES];


[director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

[director_ setView:glView];

[director_ setDelegate:self];

[director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];

if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
    CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
[sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];             // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used
[sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];      // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
[sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                   // Default on iPad is "ipad"
[sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];    // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"


[CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];


[director_ pushScene: [HelloWorldLayer scene]];


navController_ = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_];
navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;

[window_ setRootViewController:navController_];


[window_ makeKeyAndVisible];
```

That's all very well, and it works like a charm when loading the "HelloWorldLayer".
However I cannot seem to removed this "HelloWorldLayer" and make the app go back to using storyboards.
At the moment I have a function in my "HelloWorldLayer" that does the following:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView removeFromSuperview];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] removeFromParentViewController];
[self removeFromParentAndCleanup:TRUE];
```

This works well in literally removing the Cocos2D from the project, but I cannot tap anything in ViewController "A" after I have done the above: buttons do not respond to touches - it's as if the app has frozen.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

PS: Here is a link to a file that has the problem: http://www.mediafire.com/?ipnlpinl5i0lw4a

Comment: Maybe you could post a sample project that displays the simplest case of the problem.

Comment: @GradyPlayer good idea! http://www.mediafire.com/?ipnlpinl5i0lw4a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out: the `window_` that is allocated in the first line of code is still covering ViewController A. I have to call `[window_ release]` from ViewController A once the HelloWorldLayer has visually disappeared to get it out of the way.